# How to target specific rows returned by mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let's say I have a table with following columns: `id-1, id-2, col-1, col-2, col-3`
Here, id-1 is the primary key and is auto-incremented. id-2 is a different id and is not necessary to be unique. There are multiple instances of same id in that column. col-1, col-2, col-3 are just necessary columns.

---

I pass a query to select data from the table.

```
mysqli_query($connect, SELECT * FROM table WHERE id-2='some_specific_id')
```

It will return multiple rows. I would like to know how can I target specific rows, say row number 3.

Comment: WIth `LIMIT` statement

Comment: Use limit with offset to skip 2 element

Comment: Results are obtained in array, fetch the 3rd index.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to target row for. If you have certain rows to needed for certain things: eg you need all the data but you want to put them into different elements then you would need this. but if you just need one row then you need to run a query that can ascertain the correct id (probably the auto id) and then pull only that row with its associated rows from other tables where applicable.

Comment: `id-2` that won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT` to get what you want like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id-2='some_specific_id' LIMIT 2, 1;
```

Or, if you want to fetch from array, **then use the 3rd index of array**.

---

### `LIMIT` Explanation:

The following illustrates the `LIMIT` clause syntax with two arguments:

```
SELECT 
    column1,column2,...
FROM
    table
LIMIT offset , count;
```

**Let's examine the `LIMIT` clause parameters:**

- The offset specifies the offset of the first row to return. The offset of the first row is 0, not 1.
- The count specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

Comment: @KishorMalakar I can't see how `WHERE id-2` would possibly work here. I'm sure you made some kind of adjustment for this. `id-2` is equivalent and interpreted by MySQL as being `id` MINUS `2`.

Comment: Although I posted this question long back, id-2 was just something I used here to represent the second column on my table which stored some kind of id. Ofcourse in the actual application, I used some appropriate column name to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `"`:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id-2 = 'some_specific_id'");
```

---

Target specific row? Do you mean to limit the fetched rows? Or get the 3rd row?

For limiting the fetched rows, you can use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id-2='some_specific_id' LIMIT 3
```

For getting the third row:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id-2='some_specific_id' LIMIT 2, 1
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. And yes, sorry for the `"`. It skipped my eye.

Answer (score 0):

Well although it seems you just rather needed to learn basic SQL to get your answer, there is still the question in the title, that may attract other people whose problem is formulated exactly like that. So goes the answer:

Mysqli is not very convenient for this task, so we would use PDO.

- In case your query is intended to return multiple rows and you need to address one of them by number (which is rather makes little sense, but anyway), use `fetchAll()` method:

  ```
  $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id2=?");
  $stmt->execute(['some specific id']);
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
  ```

  and you will be able to address returned rows by number, starting from zero:

  ```
  echo $data[0]['col1'];
  ```
- However, it makes more sense to address the returned rows by some unique id. In this case just add this unique field fiset in the field list and then use the special [PDO street magic](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_UNIQUE):

  ```
  $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id1, table.* FROM table WHERE id2=?);
  $stmt->execute(['some specific id']);
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
  ```

  and you will be able to address returned rows by that unique field :

  ```
  echo $data[$id1]['col1'];
  ```